# Why is $ (1+\frac 1x )^x $ not defined between -1 and 0?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

When analyzing the function $$(1+\frac 1x )^x $$
I can understand the limits when it goes to plus infinity and the indetermination at x=-1, making a vertical asymptote, and when approaching it from the right, we tend towards plus infinity.
Though it is stated in my textbook (non-detailed answer) that the domain of the function does not include the interval of (-1,0), i.e: $(-\infty,-1)\bigcup(0,+\infty)$ being the domain.
I tried to make sense of this by seeing that the "even" negative numbers in between -1 and 0 would have an even root of a negative number thus not defined in R, is this the reason? or is there another explanation to it?

Comment: For $-1<x<0$ the basis is negative and the exponent is a real number, therefore we don't do real calculus on that.

Comment: @Gae, there's no problem with, say, $x=-1/3$. $(-2)^{-1/3}$ is not problematic.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I can agree with that, but the point is that it's like doing calculus on $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Koro, $(-2)^{-1/3}$ has a real value. It also has complex values, but then so does $2^{1/3}$.

Comment: Thank you folks, made things a lot clearer

Answer (score 2):

For $x$ values on $(-1, 0)$, the value $1+\frac1x$ is negative. A negative value a non-integer power is not defined.

For real valued $a$ and $x$, the value $a^x$ is usually defined as $e^{x\cdot \ln a}$, and this only exists for positive values. This can be extended additionally to include integer powers of negative numbers (i.e., $x^{k} = x\cdot x\cdots x$ where there are $k$ values of $x$), but it cannot be extended to non-integer powers of negative numbers.

Comment: That would depend on the negative power. There's nothing undefined about, say, $(-3)^{-3}$.